# I've got IndexError: list index out of range after selecting an element with xpath

Tags: python, xpath, webdriver

I made a python program using xpath and web driver for 2 different links. I would like to get the price that appears with 2 ids. This programs runs from 2 different pages that's why price has 2 ids. I used try and except but it doesn't work. I attached the code. 
Now I get IndexError: list index out of range. I will appreciate any help. Ask me any question if you want.

```html
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

# set the proxies to hide actual IP

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://218.50.2.102:8080',
    'https': 'http://185.93.3.123:8080',
}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxies)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Andrei\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe",
                          chrome_options=chrome_options)
header = ['Product title', 'Product price']

with open('csv/products.csv', "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(header)
links = ['https://www.amazon.com/Windsor-Glider-Ottoman-White-Cushion/dp/B017XRDV5S/ref=sr_1_1?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1520265105&sr=1-1&keywords=-gggg&th=1',
         'https://www.amazon.com/Instant-Pot-Multi-Use-Programmable-Packaging/dp/B00FLYWNYQ/ref=sr_1_1?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1520264922&sr=1-1&keywords=-gggh']
for i in range(len(links)):
    driver.get(links[i])
    product_title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"][1]')
    prod_title = [x.text for x in product_title]
    try:
        product_price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"][1]')
        prod_price = [x.text for x in product_price]
    except:
        print('no price v1')
    try:
        product_price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="_price"][1]')
        prod_price = [x.text for x in product_price]
    except:
        print('no price v2')
        
    csvfile = 'csv/products.csv'

    data = [prod_title[0], prod_price[0]]

    with open(csvfile, "a", newline="") as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: please improve your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just run the code and you will see what I mean

Comment: Consider searching for the specific tag you are interested in: `prod_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']').text`

Comment: I used prod_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]').text and I've got the same IndexError: list index out of range. Can you please run the program to see?

Comment: How can I use driver.find_element_by_xpath for the second link?

Comment: Sorry, you should correct your attitude. Please  read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your code is set up for your environment (exe path is for example). Give us  the exact exception message.

Comment: Ok. I will change the question. But is a limit for characters that's why I put a short title for the question.

Comment: My guess, prod_price is empty. This means that none of your price searching xpaths are giving results.

Comment: I select from the first link this xpath //span[@id="_price"]/span and it returns 13 prices. How can I have one price using xpath? For example $119.99. This link https://www.amazon.com/Windsor-Glider-Ottoman-White-Cushion/dp/B017XRDV5S/ref=sr_1_1?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1520265105&sr=1-1&keywords=-gggg&th=1

Comment: (//span[@id="_price"]/span)[1]

Comment: Thank you very much! That's it! I forgot to put it in the parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I guess I figured out your problem

You're searching for a list of elements with `find_elements_by_xpath`. In which case selenium doesn't throw an exception when nothing found. It returns an empty list. So `prod_price = [x.text for x in product_price]` assignment works in both try..except clauses. In the end you may have an empty prod_price.

You need either to check prod_price for emptiness and only then search for alternative xpath

```
prod_price = [x.text for x in product_price]
if not prod_price:
    print('no price v')
    product_price = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(......
```

or use `find_element_by_xpath` which raises an exception, using xpath for one element search

```
try:
    product_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"])[1]')
    prod_price = product_price.text
except:
.........
```

**P.S.** You could use pythonic way of iteration through an iterable

```
for link in links:
    driver.get(links)
```

Comment: You're welcome. I've added PS, about cycling through list.